# extracting getfptex batch file

Tags: tex

while loading getfptex(got it from CTAN) batch file ,when i'm extracting this batch file i'm getting series of statements saying "No Such directory" Can
anyone please help me with this.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a code sample.

Comment: this is tagged as R, but I don't see the R connection.

Comment: CTAN == CRAN with keyboard malfunction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, CTAN is the Tex archive, suggesting the getfptex is a Tex or Latex package.  A quick google suggests (to me) that it's used to help download Tex via DOS / Windows.  If this is what you want to do can I actually suggest you download and install [MikTex](http://miktex.org/).  It's a very good package for creating Tex or Latex documents on Windows and is what I use.